# Wheatpaste poster base image preparation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, cmyk, graphic-styles, art

I am looking for the steps to prepare an image (a base layer photograph) with a grayscale result like the images attached. I am not asking about the colors and embellishments.

In Photoshop I have tried various techniques for an end result in the style: Threshold Effect/CMYK Separation/Risograph/Halftone/Stipple ... no success.

What I see in these posters is a smooth graduation in the grayscale, so not a threshold/stencil/Banksy, not a silk screen Warhol effect, though some of his images do show characteristics of the style I am going for. The techniques I have tried do not reproduce the look.

Again I am only interested in learning the technique to prepare the very base layer image (photograph) to the grayscale style.

And yes I have printed a photo and then photocopied/enlarged/re-photocopied it and the result was not close. It was cool but not the technique.

Closest successful process in filter gallery:

- Artistic > Sponge (Brush Size: 0, Definition: 0, Smoothness: 7).
- Texture > Grain (Intensity: 20, Contrast: 25, Grain Type: Horizontal).
- Distort > Diffuse Glow (Graininess: 0, Glow Amount: 2, Clear Amount: 18).
- Sketch > Halftone Pattern (Size: 1, Contrast: 5, Pattern Type: Dot).
- Distort > Diffuse Glow (Graininess: 0, Glow Amount: 3, Clear Amount: 14).

[image: wheatpaste]

[image: wheatpaste]

[image: wheatpaste]

Comment: When you say base layer, do you mean the paper or the portrait on the paper?

Comment: the image below not asking about the physical preparation asking about photoshop/digital process- /  converting a photograph to the grayscale style of the images I have attached-   I know sounds simple and straightforward- you would think desaturate or turn to black and white and use levels...  that is not the approach it does not come close to achieving it-

Comment: It might help folks if you add an image of the photo you're working with, as that can potentially be part of the problem.

Comment: any photo all photos- it's not the image- it's the technique

Comment: I *think* I understand what you mean, but I don't agree that these three images have had the same treatment. The middle one has greater contrast and shows signs of some posterization/banding but not the other two.

Comment: Chances are you're overthinking it.. given the style it's doubtful the original artist was overly detailed or specific in any conversion to greyscale if there even *was* any conversion. They probably just used whatever photo they happened to find. There's little which is consistent between the greyscale images, other than the fact they are greyscale.

Comment: the middle one is a scan of an artwork- hence the greater contrast- and the other two are actual applications exposed to elements- yes I probably am overthinking it- but it's one of those techniques that I want to see how it was achieved-

Comment: It's not only technique, everyone  has mouth corners directed downwards. A kind of bad quality (=noisy, blurry, bad exposure negative, greyish positive) photo and restless composition wouldn't create the same effect with happy face.

Comment: for sure I am not after the mouth corners or changing expressions- that's not for me or this project- but good observation- if the people look like Tim Burton's Joker then it doesn't have the same weight to the commentary that is being made/or not it's art so it's nature is to be solely subjective- everyone sees it differently- no?  I am asking about the grayscale technique for base photos

Comment: I think what you like in these examples is really *the whole*: grayscale image with high contrast, cheap print, pasted on a wall, decorated with paint and drawings. You seem to seek to find a way to make images look like these images looked *before* they were printed. Can you find an example of how such a digital image would look like? Are you sure you would be able to recognize it before printing, pasting etc.?

Comment: It goes like that, look at the Monroe image, if you look better at it ... it is not one piece of paper. It is like 9 A4 papers glued next to each other. Because you have 9 papers the image is resized way bigger and this creates artifacts that don't look good, so what they do is add noise to kind of hide the artifacts and that's why you get this look. If we can call it something it is "an oversized raster image with noise on top and increased contrast" yeah

Comment: good term "an oversized raster image with noise on top and increased contrast"

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to make the BW image. I guess you are going to build something resembling in Photoshop or other software.

Not asked, but any image will not make it. You need an image where the person doesn't smile nor stare to the camera.

Remove the background:

[image]

Desaturate, add some noise (here 10% monochrome uniform) and Gaussian blur 1px to make it grainy. A film grain filter would be better.

[image]

Insert Curves adjustment layers to simulate tone loss and greyness caused by bad film exposure and bad darkroom processing or low quality printing:

[image]

You may want to test it with some colors. The possiblity to search the good tone degradation is a high advantage of adjustment layers. To be able to adjust also noise and blur they should be used as smart filters. Program Krita allows also them as adjustment layers or actually as adjustment masks as they say.

Here's some random color inserted. You may not believe beforehand how much the photo must be degraded before it fits:

[image]

You see here also a light grey, nearly white frame around the photo. It's a filled area in a new layer below the photo. The fill selection was made by Ctrl+Clicking the photo icon in the Layers panel and by expanding the selection 10 px. I guess a polygonal lasso selection would look better (=made by using scissors).

Comment: thank you for the explanation- good job on the image it is the right amount of creepy, it's the lipstick, ya know? nonetheless; it would look fantastic on a wall somewhere around the Bristol area... cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The final effect of converting a colour image to a black and white image will very much depend on the source image, so you will get a different look each time.

I also suspect there's a possibility that the originals may have been scanned newsprint, rather than photos converted to greyscale.

Anyway, one possibility is to use the Adobe Camera RAW filer on an image converted to a smart object to get the general tonality and grain, first using the B&W mixer, then adding rough grain in Effects, and also possibly a curves adjustment to boost the contrast a touch.

[image]

Now to degrade the image further, and make it look a bit more like news print, find a rough paper texture, with flecks in it, desaturate and invert it so the flecks are white and background is dark, and use a curves adjustment to increase the contrast - so you basically have a texture which consists of white flecks on a black background, something like this

[image]

Have this texture on a layer above your smart object, and clip it to that object, and set the layer blending mode to Screen, maybe bring down the layer opacity a bit

Here's an example

[image]

Comment: oi, that's the chutney...  I like it- thank you for explanation

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this answer shows how to make a *digital simulation* of photo of an image which is poorly printed and pasted on a wall. This is not the steps needed if you actually were to make a *physical* print and paste it on a wall. I misunderstood the question it seems.